# explanation of the nested for loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=5; i>=1;i--)
  {
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
    {
      printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I wanted to know that what is the role of `i` and `j` in this code show does the loop decide what to put in rows and what in columns? Please explain the whole loop in each and every detail possible btw I am new here! Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Comment: The role of variables is to store values of a specific type.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question...

Comment: If you have access to a debugger (hint: you do, and for free) you could step through this code and see yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Let's work from the outside in.

```
for ( i = 5; i >= 1; i-- )
{
  loop-body
}
```

The sequence of operations is as follows:

1. Initialize `i` to `5` (`i = 5`);
2. If `i >= 1` is true then goto 3, else goto 6;
3. Execute *`loop-body`*
4. Subtract `1` from `i` (`i--`)
5. Goto 2;
6. Exit loop.

So, the sequence of statements in *`loop_body`* is executed 5 times - each time the loop executes, `i` goes from 5, to 4, to 3, to 2, to 1, to 0.  When `i` reaches `0`, the condition `i >= 1` is no longer true, and the loop exits at that point.

Breaking it down a bit more:

```
for ( i = 5; i >= 1; i-- )
{
  inner-loop
  printf("\n");
}
```

`printf("\n")` writes a newline character to standard output - any output following this will be written on a new line.  So now our sequence is

1. Initialize `i` to `5`;
2. If `i >= 1` is true then goto 3, else goto 7;
3. Execute *`inner-loop`*;
4. Write a newline character to standard output;
5. Subtract `1` from `i`;
6. Goto 2;
7. Exit loop.

Jumping straight to the finish:

```
for ( i = 5; i >= 1; i-- )
{
  for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++ )
  {
    printf("*");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Our sequence of operations is now:

1. Initialize `i` to `5`;
2. If `i >= 1` is true then goto 3, else goto 10;
3. Initialize `j` to `1`;
4. If `j <= i` is true, then goto 5, else goto 8;
5. Write a `*` character to standard output;
6. Add `1` to `j` (`j++`);
7. Goto 4;
8. Write a newline to standard output;
9. Goto 2;
10. Exit loop;

Calling `printf("*");` five times in a row results in `*****` being written to standard output.  Calling it four times in a row results in `****` being written.  If you call `printf("\n");` in between, you get

```
*****
****
```

Comment: Thank u so much ! For such a detailed answer I appreciate it so much

Answer (score 0):

At first, the outer loop sets `i` to `5`. The inner loop then repeats `5` times, as it goes from `1` to `5`. Therefore `*****` is printed. After the inner loop, `'\n'` is printed. That means we continue on the second row.
The outer loop decrements `i` to `4`, which means the inner one is only repeated `4` times, respectively. So it prints `****` and after that, the `'\n'` follows. We continue on the next row.
The outer loop decrements `i` to `3`, which means the inner one is only repeated `3` times, respectively. So it prints `***` and after that, the `'\n'` follows.  This is continued until `i` is `1`. That means, that the last loop only prints `*`. After that, the loop is done and the program ends.
So basically `i` and `j` are determining how often the loop is repeated.

Comment: Ur answer was the most easiest to understand thank u

Answer (score 0):

When you use loops, you need a "counter", basically a variable that changes if something happens, and the loop will terminate if the counter reaches a certain number. `i` and `j` are your counters here. This is a very generic definition, you should research programming loops.

`int i,j;` initializes variables named `i` and `j` without giving them values.

`for(i=5; i>=1;i--)` says: `i` equals 5, while `i` is greater than or equal to 1, decrement `i` by 1 (This is what `i--` means).

Within this loop is `for(j=1; j<=i; j++)` loop, which says: `j` equals 1, while `j` is less than or equal to `i` (which is originally 5, but decrements while the outer loop iterates), *increment* `j`, or increase by one (`j++` means increase by one).

Each loop features a `printf` statement that is meant to print "*" or a new line (`\n`) as the outer loop and inner loop iterate.

`return 0` terminates the program